# How to make http.get() request to node.js from angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I'm trying to http.get() request to node.js from angular
in institute.ts.

```js
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
export class InstituteListPage {
  data: any =[];
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  this.getData();
  }
getData(){
        let URL = "http//localhost:3005/institute";
        console.log(URL);
       this.http.get(URL).subscribe(data => { console.log("****************"   ,data)},
          err => {
            let alert = this.AlertC.create(
              {
                title:"ERROR",
                message:err,
                buttons: [
                  {
                    text:"OK",
                    role:"cancel"
                
                  }
                ]
              }
            );
            alert.present();
          })
          
  }
  }
```

When I run this code, I get

> GET `http://localhost:8100/http//localhost:3005/institute 404` (Not
>   Found)

while the http post request works fine

How can I get it done?

Comment: May I suggest you to change the title of your question? Right know it is over-specific which may lead to this question being overlooked by those who could help.

Comment: try `let URL = "http://localhost:3005/institute";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the issue here is misspelled schema in your URL. It should be `http://` otherwise this URL will be (and actually is) treated by Angular as a relative one